# IntelliJ idea network connecting failure

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea

I can't get connection to network in **IntelliJ idea 15** after I have set up all the basic configurations of the project and used **tomcat** server to access the internet, at first, I find my tomcat wouldn't running, so in order to find out where went wrong, I simply used a test server instead of tomcat to connect internet, if I can get HTML data through the quest of test server from the website("www.Google.com" for instance, and I tested several sites), then it shall proves that there's something wrong with my tomcat server. But unfortunately, I can't get any data from the website and the server console kept showing those lines suggesting my network had connection problems. here's the request code I use to access to Internet in **JAVA** .

[request code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0leE2.png)

[request code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Brm4.png)

It must something wrong with my IDEA or computer network settings.
Someone to help me figure this problem out please, thank u so much!

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Software caused
>   connection abort: recv failed     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)    at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)   at
>
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:675)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
>         at    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>         at csc.cn.cscb.bussion.MallStoreMod.read_html(MallStoreMod.java:217)
>         at csc.cn.cscb.test.HSHTest.read_html(HSHTest.java:117)     at csc.cn.cscb.test.HSHTest.main(HSHTest.java:26)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at    com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>          Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please be more detailed and explain what does "even after I tried serval methods" means. What methods? Can you share the code you are trying to run?

Comment: Do you need to configure an http proxy??

Answer (score 0):

Try to open a browser against the server. You should get a connection with some sort of response or an error. Check if your server is expecting HTTPS (SSL/TLS) or not, as your client is attempting an HTTP only connection.

Answer (score 0):

What Java version is used to run your code? It could be that the Java version you are using is old, contains known security issues and is therefore blocked by your antivirus.

Or there is a proxy in your network that [must be explicitly configured for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) to be able to connect to external resources.

Also check your firewall configuration, outgoing connections can be blocked either intentionally or by a erroneous configuration (or must be explicitly permitted per application/process).

Comment: My Java version is idk 1.8, and the same project works totally fine at my co-worker's computer. I shut down both the windows firewalls and windows defender. The second solution you mentioned above I'd like to know how to check the settings or configurations? Thx

Comment: 1.8 is not a complete version string, there are 1.8 builds released a year and more ago with known security problems. Try the most recent build.